# Is there a way to add domain suggestions for email when user type @ symbol in text field

Tags: ios, swift, uikeyboard

I am dealing with one implementation like I need to add domain (like gmail.com, hotmail.com, yahoo.com) suggestions on above the iOS standard keyboard.

I tried to find way to add in auto-correction tab. but, no luck.

Please let me know how we can implement this.

Comment: The question is to broad in my opinion but a term to google is "autocomplete", here is one similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35629285/how-to-create-autocomplete-text-field-in-swift

Comment: The premise is very simple (as they often are). As the user's input changes, simply query your collection of possibilities (i.e. gmail.com) against that input using greater than and less than or equal. If the collection contains a string greater than the current input AND less than or equal to that input + `u{10ffff}`, then suggest that string.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thank you for your response. This is related to auto-completed text. I am looking for auto-suggestion needs to show above iOS Keyboard.

Comment: I have found the way to show a view above the keyboard using keyboard variable inputAccessoryView.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a `UIScrollView` for `UITextField.inputAccessoryView` and adding buttons to scrollView, like so:

```
emailBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.952941, green: 0.952941, blue: 0.952941, alpha: 1.0)
textField.inputAccessoryView = emailBar
```

And add `UIButton` for each email provider

```
var lastX: CGFloat = 8.0
let emailProviders = ["hotmail.com", "gmail.com", "yahoo.com", "mail.ru", "yahoo.com", "mail.ru"]
for provider in emailProviders {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.setTitle(provider, for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.286275, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0), for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(appendEmailProvider(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16.0, weight: .light)
    button.sizeToFit()
    button.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: lastX, y: 4.0)
    emailBar.addSubview(button)
    lastX += button.frame.width + 12.0
}
emailBar.contentSize = CGSize(width: lastX, height: 32.0)
```

Next we add events for `UITextField`

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange), for: .editingChanged)
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange), for: .touchDown)

@objc func textFieldDidChange() {
    guard
        let selectedRange = textField.selectedTextRange,
        let pos1 = textField.position(from: selectedRange.end, offset: 0),
        let pos2 = textField.position(from: selectedRange.end, offset: -1),
        let range = textField.textRange(from: pos1, to: pos2),
        textField.text(in: range) == "@"
    else {
        emailBar.isHidden = true
        return
    }

    emailBar.contentOffset.x = 0
    emailBar.isHidden = false
}

@objc func appendEmailProvider(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if let textRange = textField.selectedTextRange, let provider = sender.title(for: .normal) {
        textField.replace(textRange, withText: provider)
    }
}
```