# How to make TextField that provides options for user to choose in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I want to make a TextField where user gets options to choose from upon direct input. And then use selected value later in code.
For example.
User start typing "Lon", and gets options to choose in dropdown type menu:
"London, UK"
"London, Ohio, USA"
"London, Kentucky, USA"
User choses "London, UK" and its gets selected as starting point.
Same trick with end point
I know it's somehow possible with Picker, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: If the OS built-in „predictive text“ is not enough, you will need your own custom solution. Maybe modify from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43306951/16157878